# How to establish a successful SQL Server Connection to an Android App in Android App Studio

Tags: android, sql-server

I am working on an Android App for my Mobile Software Engineering class for grad school and I am a bit in a bind. I am having troubles establishing my connection. Can some one assist me with this? I have a database in the cloud that is free on somee.com that I use which is a SQL Server Database. Here is the information:

MS SQL Server address:

```
Testdev.mssql.somee.com
```

Login name:

```
 vahharris_SQLLogin_1
```

Login password:

```
 bjl58ms4iy
```

Connection string:   workstation id=Testdev.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=vahharris_SQLLogin_1;pwd=bjl58ms4iy;data source=Testdev.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=Testdev

Here is my current code

```
 package com.test.keeptraq;

 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.Statement;


 public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_1);
    try{

        // Set the connection string
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        String username = "vahharris_SQLLogin_1 ";
        String password = "bjl58ms4iy";

        Connection DBconn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://Testdev.mssql.somee.com/Testdev;user="+username+";password="+password);
        Log.w("Connection","open");

        Statement stmt = DBconn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("select * from Customer");

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_label);
        text.setText(resultSet.getString(1));

        DBconn.close();

    }catch(Exception e){

        Log.w("Error connection",""+ e.getMessage());


    }

}
```

}

Comment: What does “having troubles” mean? You're getting an error message? Post it. You're not getting the result you expected? Post what you expected and what you got.

Comment: Please don't post your username and password online like this.  Anybody can now connect to your database, which is obviously a security issue.

Comment: I am not getting the result. I am not receving an error at all. I am just not getting results.  My results need to show in the textview and it's not

Comment: Dan J. Thanks. I put it up here cause it's a dummy DB I use. Never used for production purposes. So I'm alright. Appreciate your concern though.

Answer (score 0):

Your username seems to have a trailing space in its definition:

```
String username = "vahharris_SQLLogin_1 ";
```

You haven't posted what error you're seeing, but if it's a failure to login, that might be the cause.

Comment: Dan J, How does the rest of the code look? Does it look right? It is not populating an error but it still does not show results.